# WSO2 - Governance Registry - 'Preprequest action must be completed' Error being thrown

Tags: wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

I have defined a new artifact type and am successfully creating new asset instances of it in the publisher - which works well.  Recently I was experimenting with my own create_form.hbs under publisher/extensions/assets//themes/default/partials/ and then decided against continuing.  After deleting the newly created '/themes/default/partials/create_form.hbs' I then found that when I now try to publish a new instance of the artifact I get the following error thrown:

> [2016-11-11 11:17:06,833] ERROR -  Failed to invoke action: Create for the asset of id: "9a3a4e55-a5a3-4c94-a2d0-152a10e4ab45".The following exception was thrown: JavaException: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Preprequest action must be completed before Create {rxt.asset}
>   [2016-11-11 11:17:06,833] ERROR -  org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Preprequest action must be completed before Create {asset_api_endpoints}
>
> org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Preprequest action must be completed before Create (eval code#1(eval)#87) at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754) at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148) at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:22

Despite this and the fact that I get the user friendly 'Error' message in the publication page telling me the asset was unable to be created, the new instance **does in fact get created** (I can see it when I go the the asset list page).  I can also edit with no problems.

I'm unsure whether this error is related to the create_form.hbs page I previously created (and then deleted) or whether it is just a coincidence.

Is there a caching problem going on?

Any help on what the error means and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace to analyse? Have you restarted the server after deleting the hbs file?

Comment: apparently, you have updated an asset.js file or something related to publisher API. Can you describe the changes carried out?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Finally tracked it down to the defaultAction (under meta lifecycle) in the asset file.  I had a value defined (Create) which didn't match what I had in the LifeCycle config.

Answer (score 5):

The defaultAction value (under meta lifecycle) in the asset file was defined as "Create" which didn't match what was in the LifeCycle config.  This action must match a valid lifecycle value otherwise the publish page displays an error message despite successfully creating the new asset.